# Leaflet - Custom Map does not load - Wrong File Size?

Tags: customization, leaflet

Something like "OpenStreetMaps" works fine!
Everything is ok, Zoom and Marker works, small Code...

But when i add my own Url, the Tiles are get not loaded !
So i think there is something wrong with my Image Size ? Pixel ?
Leaflet Tutorial just say "add a Map Url"

Look in my Code there is a Notice with Examples,
i think this is not a "coding" Error, more like a File Error.
I hope somebody has a idea :-)

http://hizi.xyz/Map/

Comment: What url are you trying to add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `http://www.hizi.xyz/Map/{z}/{x}/{y}.png` as your base URL, but your tiles are actually at `http://www.hizi.xyz/Map/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png`.

At the zoom level you've initialized the map (11), you will not be able to see your custom tiles anyway, so you should set `maxZoom: 5` in the map options. Also, your tiles only cover the northwestern quadrant of the map (from 0-85 degrees north and 0-180 degrees west), so you will either want to restrict panning within those bounds by setting the `maxBounds` option, or (if you actually want the map to be global) modify the directory structure by lowering the index for each of the {z} directories by 1. The following code should work to load your map as it is and prevent users from getting outside the boundaries of your map tiles:

```
var southWest = L.latLng(0, -180),
    northEast = L.latLng(85, 0),
    bounds = L.latLngBounds(southWest, northEast);

var map = L.map('map', {maxZoom: 5, maxBounds: bounds}).setView([42.5, -90], 3);

L.tileLayer('http://www.hizi.xyz/Map/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png').addTo(map);
```

If, for aesthetic reasons, you want to keep the map from wrapping at the world boundaries, you may also want to set `noWrap: true` in the tileLayer options, i.e.:

```
L.tileLayer('http://www.hizi.xyz/Map/tiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {noWrap: true}).addTo(map);
```

Here is an example fiddle that shows it working:

http://jsfiddle.net/nathansnider/6qeL29sm/